# Are RecIds unique across Common tables in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++

Are the RecIds unique across `Common` tables in AX 2012? I read that this is version dependent, but I did not manage to find any information on this for AX 2012.

If not, doesn't that break polymorphic design of the tables in AX, where all AX tables extend from `Common`? And `Common` declares `RecId`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Microsoft Dynamics AX inserts records into SQL tables, [a unique RecId is assigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/systemsequence.aspx) to each record regardless of the company each record is associated with. The field is 64 bit long and unique per table.

In Axapta 3.0 and below RecIds were unique per company account and 32 bit long. Thus a company could have no more than 4 billion records as the RecId could be negative.

Polymorphic design? I am not sure what you mean in this context, but given a RecId you do not know which table it belongs to, and you need that information in order to find the record:

```
public Common findRecord(TableId _tableId, RecId _recId) 
{
    Common record = new DictTable(_tableId).makeRecord();
    select record where record.RecId == _recId; 
    return record; 
}
```

In SQL no table is called Common. It is an AX concept, you may consider it an interface containing methods only.

Comment: By "polymorphic design" I mean that all tables inherit from `Common`. I meant that in a way: if we have a `Car` with Id property `LicencePlate` and two specializations `Truck` and `FamilyCar`, it should not be possible that an instance of Truck and an instance of FamilyCar have the same LicensePlate. But I guess, the RecId is just not the LicencePlate, it is not Id across all Common objects. Your interface comparison explains it the best. Thank you!

Comment: Giving more information to the nice *Jan B. Kjeldsen* expanation and polimorfism subject, if you use the new (AX 2012) inherited tables with a `Common` class (it's a class or an interface, but never a table as it doesn't exists in the database), you'll find that both the parent and all child tables will share the `RecId` of the main table. This way you can manage this polymorphic design with inherited tables too.