# Dynamic ax 2012 2 table have the same recid

Tags: axapta, x++

In Dynamic ax 2012 wmsOrderTrans and salesLine tables have 50% same recId.
Could someone tell me how that can be?

[image]

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23899445

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Record IDs are unique within a table, but can be duplicated between other tables.

The system stores what the next RecId will be for each table independently.

You can read a more in-depth explanation on this blog here: http://deepakdyanmicsax.blogspot.com/2014/03/record-ids-in-ax-2012_5.html