# Is there a way to make a select query where you join two tables that doesnt have relation between them?

Tags: sql, select, x++, dynamics-365

I have 2 tables and they doesnt have relation. All they have is find display method...
Table1 has description and Table2 has translations for that description. My goal is to make a select query that compares my field with all translations and if it finds specific translation, it should return Table1 description in default translation.

As example:
Table1 has description "Hi" and in Table2 There is translations for that word in many languages. On excel i have field "Privet" and it should search in Table2 if that translation exists. If it does, it should return "Hi"

My current code:

```
LanguageTxt         languageTxt;
AstIGruTareType     tareType;

    select Description from tareType
         join languageTxt
             where languageTxt.RecId == tareType.RecId && languageTxt.Txt == _tareType;

    return tareType.Description;
```

Table1 stands for TareType and Table2 stands for LanguageTxt...
If i only select LanguageTxt, everything works fine, but i have to return orginal language from tareType.description, but when i try to add this join, its just empty.. Can someone explain how and why is this happening?

TareType table:
Hi ||
Test ||
Bye

LanguageTxt table(all translations for word "Hi"):
Sveiki ||
Привет ||
γεια

Excel file has field value "Привет"

When im importing excel file to my journal, it should compare that field with languageTxt Table. Value "Привет" exists, so it should return original language value (Hi).

If i select only Table1 or only Table2, it prints out everything. If i join them together, then theres nothing inside...

Edit- Maybe i could join them With RecId or TableId?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what data you are working with nor what you want as a result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added example

Comment: Take a look how relations on `LanguageTxt` are defined for other standard tables, e.g. `DlvMode`. You need to add a similar relation for your custom table.

Comment: I did some searches and i found out, that i can connect these 2 tables with TareType.recId == Language.txtRecId. My mistake was that i wrote Language.recId

Comment: You might want to read [Are RecIds unique across Common tables in Dynamics AX 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899445/are-recids-unique-across-common-tables-in-dynamics-ax-2012) and add `TareType.TableId == LanguageTxt.TxtTableId` to your code.